# Ignite messaging: transient field are not discarded

Tags: ignite

In case of a single node cluster, when sending a message (unordered and async, in case this matters) we noticed that the listenr is recieving the object **with** all of its transient fields.

This behavior is different from an ignite cache where the cacheed object seems to be stripped away from all its transient fields thanks to a `ctx.getCacheObject()` call.

Is it possible to have ignite messaging do the same ?